# Как расположить View от toolbar до view

Tags: android

Не могу расположить RecyclreView от тулбара(Там где написано "Home") до верхней границы BottomNavigationView. пробовал инструметом Studio.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red"
android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0FAA0F"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Пробовал разные схемы, добавлял и такое в RecyclerView

```
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
```

Результат одинаковый, остается промежуток между тулбаром и RecyclerView так же нижняя граница уходит за BottomNavigationView хотя хотелось бы чтобы она была только до верхней границы BottomNavigationView 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же я вставил в recyclerView app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/red">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется вам надо убрать android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да это помогло, спасибо, а как сделать так чтобы recycler view был только до верхней границы BottomNavigationView, можно конечно сделать просто marginBottom 24dp, но правильно ли будет так сделать?

Comment: app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"

Comment: Я так пробовал, должно было бы работать, но в view я вижу что он идет под BottomNavigationView. Вложил еще одну картинку

Comment: Лучше покажите разметку. Может у вас там лишнее или надо высоту в 0dp поставить

Comment: Обновил вопрос, вставил в конец новый код

Comment: Добавьте привязку верха к верху родителя и поставьте высоту в 0dp

Comment: Ага, так выглядит разметка правильной, но в этом случае если список будет пустой или там только два элемента, я буду видеть background parent. я только учусь, и могу просто поменять backgroundcolor ConstraintLayout или же внутри него создать еще один ConstraintLayout и уже туда поместить recyclerView, но в этом случае я не смогу скролить. Но я думаю про скрол я уже должен создать другой вопрос перед этим погуглив и поразмыслив как это сделать

Comment: Как бы поместить ваши коментарии в ответы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Убрать лишний паддинг у родительского элемента.
2. Привязать нижний край RecyclerView к верху BottomNavigationView `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"`
3. Верхний край RecyclerView  привязать к верху экрана `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"`
4. Высоту RecyclerView  поставить в `0dp`